# How to set ffplay's backgroud color if frame size has a different aspect ratio than the window's?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

If frame size has a different aspect ratio than the window's, ffplay will stuff black bar into its window area. How to replace the black bar's color? Sometimes I apply a crop filter to ffplay to cut off black bars inside the video frame, and if ffplay stuff non-black bars into the window, it'll be more convenient for me to see whether I've cropped accurately.

Comment: Does [FFmpeg Filters Documentation - Pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) answer your question?

Comment: No. Video filter pad is used to put the original frame onto an expanded frame, then stuffing the area between the original frame's border and the expanded frame's border with the color specified by user, rather than what I wanted that keeping the frame size and just stuff into ffplay's window. Thanks for your reply! @DavidPostill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run ffplay it resizes to fit the video, so not sure why you are having an issue.

If you just want to check correct aspect ratio, read the post linked below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422387/get-aspect-ratio-of-video-from-ffmpeg

Alternatively, the following code will play a file when you drag it onto the script. This code removes the ffplay border, so as long as your background is not black, it should highlight any remaining, unwanted black padding.

```
 for %%F in (%*) do (
 ffplay -i "%%~fF" -an -noborder
 shift)
 exit
```

Note: `-an` disables audio to save time searching for an audio device (speakers/headphones) connected to the output during start of playback. Remove this if you want audio, and have a device connected.

Edit.

If seeking a single pixel at the border, the following can be added after `-noborder`.

```
 -vf crop=iw*0.5:ih*0.5:0:0,scale=2*iw:2*ih:flags=neighbor
```

This will display the top left quarter of the video at two times size, effectively doubling the pixels during playback.
If your videos are small, as suggested in your comment, you may only need the scale filter. For larger videos the crop ensures the video does not show full screen, hiding the border. Just bare in mind the true number of the black pixels width, if present, has been multiplied by the scale factor during playback.

Comment: Hiding ffplay's window border is an acceptable alternative, thank you! As I said previously, I want to check whether I've cropped black bars inside the video frame correctly. For a cropped tiny-sized video still having a 1-pixel-wide residual black bar inside its frame, if ffplay's background color is bright, it'll easier for me to find that 1-pixel-wide residual black bar after maximized ffplay's window.

Comment: If just seeking a single pixel, view my edit in answer.